# onSelect tax calculations

Tags: javascript, options-menu, onselect, sales-tax

My work is only required to charge California State residents sales tax when they make a purchase. I wrote what I hoped would be a javascript function that will apply sales tax when the customer selects California from a drop down list of states. I gave each state a value of 'else' and california a value or 'CA'. My code calculates the sales tax as 0 everytime, causing tax to never be applied to the grand total when "CA" is selected. I am using onSelect=UpdateCost() for my state list, and onChange=UpdateCost() when check boxes of products are checked. What part of my code is preventing the tax from properly calculating?

```
 function UpdateCost() {
   var stotal = 0;
   var ttotal = 0;
   var gtotal = 0;
   var tax = .0825;
   var gn, elem;
     for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
       gn = 'manual'+i;
       elem = document.getElementById(gn);
     if (elem.checked == true) { stotal += Number(elem.value); }
}
   var state = document.getElementById('state');
   var selection = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value;
 if (selection = 'CA') { ttotal += tax * stotal; }
 if (selection = 'else') {ttotal = 0;}
 if(!isNaN(ttotal)) {
    var calitax = ttotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('taxtotal').value = calitax;
    document.getElementById('subtotal').value = stotal.toFixed(2);
    }
   var gtotal = ttotal + stotal;
     if(!isNaN(gtotal)) {
   var grand = gtotal.toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById('grandtotal').value = grand;}

   }
```

And here is the relevant form code that has been simplified (as simple as I could get it anyway):

```
//in the header of course.
<script type="text/javascript" src="orderform.js"></script>

<form action=""  method="post">
<fieldset>
State: <select name="state" id="state" onSelect="UpdateCost()">
<option value="else" id="else">AL</option>
<option value="else" id="else">AK</option>
<option value="else" id="else">AZ</option>
<option value="else" id="else">AR</option>
<option value="CA" id="CA">CA</option>
</select>
<p>Select the manuals to order</p>

<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual6' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="185">manual 1<br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual0' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="220">manual 2<br /><br />

<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual7' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="155">manual 3<br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual1' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="185">manual 4<br /><br />

<h3>**SAVE $50** WHEN YOU BUY BOTH</h3><br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual8' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="290">manual 5<br />
Or:<br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual2' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="355">manual 6<br /><br />
<hr>
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual9' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="190">manual 7<br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual3' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="225">manual 8<br /><br />

<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual10' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="125">manual 9<br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual4' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="150">manual 10<br /><br />
<h3>**SAVE $50** WHEN YOU BUY BOTH</h3><br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual11' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="265">11<br />
Or:<br />
<input name="manual" type="checkbox" id='manual5' onclick="UpdateCost()" value="325">12<br /><br />

Subtotal: <input name="subtotal" type="text" id="subtotal" value=""><br />
California Resident Tax: <input name="taxtotal" type="text" id="taxtotal" value=""><br />
Total: <input name="grandtotal" type="text" id="grandtotal" value=""><br />

</fieldset>
```

Sorry for the length!!! Thank you for the help :D

Comment: Why not open the debugger and have the browser tell you, rather than one of us? (F12 = IE, Ctrl-Shift-I = Chrome, FF, Opera)

Comment: I'm super new to Javascript, and I have been working on this for days. I'm self taught, so I am trial and error-ing my way through creating this function. If I could figure it out on my own I wouldn't have signed up for a stackoverflow account and posted here >.<

Comment: Can't argue with "wouldn't have signed up for a SO account and posted here > <" :-)  _BUT_ I will point out that the question should include a minimal (but complete!) code snippet that demonstrates the problem. It's really a bit hard to see things working without seeing the data too..

Comment: Also, just opened the debugger for Chrome and it isn't indicating any issues with my code, so I would image that its not that my code is "wrong" but that I am not using the correct code/order to calculate the sales tax. I just don't know what the correct line of code would be :/ I can add a snippit of the form that it is tied to

Comment: Bugger! The debugger also has single-step and breakpoints available. You can single-step through each line of the function and examine the value of any/all variables within it. This may help isolate the problem. But yes, a copy of the html it processes would aid in providing a solution. :-)

Comment: I know that is a crap ton of html, and I'm really sorry. I took out most of the states and all other unnecessary crap to try to get it as minimal as possible while preserving the integrity of what I created. Thank you for your help enhzflep :D I really appreciate it!

Comment: Problem #1, `onSelect="UpdateCost()"` should be `onChange="UpdateCost()"`

Answer (score 0):

You had two problems. The first was you were using `onSelect` instead of `onChange` in the state select field. The bigger issue however was in the function where you were checking the state. You were using an assignment `=` instead of a comparison `==`.

```
if (selection == 'CA') {    
    ttotal += tax * stotal;
}
if (selection == 'else') {
    ttotal = 0;
}
```

Fixed **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WYQag/)**.